# Need to make a full-page slider with a video on it

Tags: html, css, video, slider

So, I'm somewhat a beginner with code and all this stuff. I need to make a full-page slider, with a video as one of the slides. It must wait for the video to finish playing in order to proceed to the next slide.

I managed something near my goal by using  to embed the video (it is stored in a folder in my pc), but it just plays and stops, sometimes the slider goes on without it even finishing, and I can't help but think there should be a better, more efficient way.

I'm using bootstrap and thought of applying it to this template: 
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/

Comment: Can you paste some code to show how you've implemented the video loading and playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the video inside one of the bootstrap carousel items, like this:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <video src="myvideo.mpg" id="myVideo"></video>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then listen to the "ended" event to go to the next item once the video has finished playing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel({ interval: false}); // this prevents the auto-loop

    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

    function myHandler(e) {
        $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel('next');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem was not knowing about the <video> tag... As I said, beginner. Now I'm facing a problem where I want to have a smaller slider down the page, but the larger one's CSS is overriding it. Can I assing a different CSS only to the smaller one?

Comment: Of course. You just need to assign a custom class to the smaller slider and define it's property in the CSS. PS: If you found my answer useful you should set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Right, so I changed the site a bit and I'm having another minor issue. I have two bootstrap sliders and a separate js script for each one. However one of the scripts is affecting both. Is there a way to apply the script only to one of the sliders? Like, "JS should only apply to the content of this <div>?"

Comment: Comments are not meant to start a long chat about whatever problem you might encounter during the development of your product. You should ask another question if you need more help on different aspects of the code.